# How to use Sessions in Codeigniter pre_system hooks

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, hook

I am  trying to change some config variables depends on SESSION data. I use session_start and set some variables in session, it works normally. But when I logout system and clear sessions, codeigniter doesn't clear and destroy the data in session.

Ci_session cleared but PHPSESSID doesn't change value, I think codeigniter uses PHPSESSID and again set all session values. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of session]

Comment: Have you tried regenerating a new `session` on logout? (not sure if that's best practice)

Comment: Yes, I have tried but didn't work 
`session_regenerate_id();
        setcookie('PHPSESSID','',time()-1,'','',1);
        header("Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=abc; path=/; domain=s.com");`

Comment: According to [setcookie documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) the function must be run before any output, and you're leaving the value blank. That may be the issue! Have you tried setting a value, it's the second option to pass in the `setcookie()` function.

Comment: I tried just now same result : `   
    setcookie('PHPSESSID',md5(time()),-1,'','',1);    
   `